# previous selected value also append in textarea but i want only one (current) selected value append in textarea

Tags: jquery

previous selected value also append in textarea but i want only one (current) selected value append in textarea

[click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2BBC.jpg)

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).click("click", function(e) {
    if ((e.target.value != undefined) && (e.target.id == "checkit")) {

      if ((e.target.id != "if") && (e.target.id != "while")) {

        $('#sms_text').val($('#sms_text').val() + e.target.value + '\n');

      }
    }
  });
  //   second

  $('#mc_nos').change(function() {
    if ($('#mc_nos option:selected')) {
      $("#mc_nos option:selected").addClass("important");

    }

  });

  $(document).change("change", function(e) {

    if ((e.target.value != undefined) && (e.target.id == "mc_nos")) {

      if ($("#mc_nos option:selected")) {


        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
          if ($(this).attr("class") == "important") {

            $('#sms_text').val(e.target.value + '\n' + $('#sms_text').val());

          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

i want to append values both leftside buttons(screenshot) and select box option values.

select box option values only append one current selected option

Comment: clear the textarea before appending new value

Comment: i want to clear select box options only, remaining values(leftside button values in screenshot) will not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi since i dont know how your HTML looks like I am just addressing your question and have created a demo.. kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/hscrhokc/2/

**UPDATED**
https://jsfiddle.net/hscrhokc/7/

**HTML**

```
<select class="dd">
   <option>1111111111</option>
  <option>6666666666</option>
  <option>7777777777</option>
  <option>8888888888</option>
  <option>9999999999</option>

</select>

<div class="menu">
  <span>some text1</span>
  <span>some text2</span>
  <span>some text3</span>
  <span>some text4</span>
</div>

<br>

<textarea class="ta">
fdsfdsf
ewqew
bnmnmnm
</textarea>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu').on('click', 'span', function(){
    $('.ta').prepend($(this).text()+'\n');
  });

  $('.dd').on('change', function(){
    var taVal=  $('.ta').text(); // store textara text in a variable
    var taArr=taVal.split("\n"); // split string into words and store it as an array taArr

    // traverse throug the dropdown
      $('.dd option').each(function(i){

      // check whether the dropdown value exists in textarea text
        if($.inArray(this.value,taArr)!=-1){
            $('.ta').text(taVal.replace(this.value+'\n', '')); // if found remove it

        }
      });

      //prepend the selected dropdown value to textarea
    $('.ta').prepend($('.dd').val()+'\n');

  });
});
```

Comment: I have checked for multiple values you can refer to the jsfiddle demo

Comment: which line should you delete?

Comment: you didnt mention about that in your question... you wanted to remove the value which is in dropdown and thats what the demo does,,, now can you please elaborate  your question so that I can understand clearly

Comment: this is not a task.just do this steps.fist click on textarea and delete any value.next you will check once demo

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

*some points you should know*

***1st:*** use `!==` instead of `!=`

***2nd:*** use

```
$('#mc_nos').change(function() {
  $("#mc_nos option").removeClass("important");
  $("#mc_nos option:selected").addClass("important");
});
```

instead of

```
$('#mc_nos').change(function() {
     if($('#mc_nos option:selected')){
        $("#mc_nos option:selected").addClass("important");
     } 
});
```

***3rd:*** if you need to check

```
if($('#mc_nos option:selected'))
```

use

```
if($('#mc_nos option').is(':selected'))
// or
if($('#mc_nos option:selected').length > 0)
```

***4th:*** to check for class

```
if($(this).attr("class")=="important")
```

use instead

```
if($(this).hasClass("important"))  // if has class
// or
if(!$(this).hasClass("important"))  // if not
```

***5th:*** about the append point .. you can work with hidden span for example 
.. say you have a span

```
<span class="saveselected" style="display:none;"></span>
```

when you append the selected data  catch the span previous text then replace the span text in textarea value with 'nothing' then append the new text to span again .. something like this

```
if($('span.saveselected').text().trim() !== ''){  // if span not empty
  var span_previous_text = $('span.saveselected').text(); // get span previous text
  var textarea_previous_value = $('#sms_text').val(); // get textarea current value
  var new_textarea_value = textarea_previous_value.replace(span_previous_text ,''); // replace the span text in textarea with '' 
  $('#sms_text').val(new_textarea_value); // all data again without the previous selected data
}
```