# how remove unselected(previous selected) class names

Tags: jquery

```
<select id="mc_nos">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>


$('#mc_nos').change(function() {
     if($('#mc_nos option:selected')){
        $("#mc_nos option:selected").addClass("important");
     } 
});
```

i selected first option.i got output like this

```
<select id="mc_nos">
<option class="important">1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
```

i selected second option.i got output like this

```
<select id="mc_nos">
<option class="important">1</option>
<option  class="important">2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
```

But i want output like this

```
<select id="mc_nos">
<option>1</option>
<option class="important">2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
```

when I am selecting first option this option only adding Class name
next I am selecting second or third.....  that options only addClass
remaining class will remove
how remove unselected(previous selected) class names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove class from previously selected element, also there is no need for if condition it will be always true.

```js
$('#mc_nos').change(function() {
  // remove class for elements which is not selected
  $("option:not(:selected)", this).removeClass("important");
  $("option:selected", this).addClass("important");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mc_nos">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @swaroopkomma : glad to help :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107838/previous-selected-value-also-append-in-textarea-but-i-want-only-one-current-se

Comment: @swaroopkomma : do you want to clear entire text from textarea?

Comment: append both leftside button values and selected option values but seleted option values append only current value(one) remaing will remove(not leftside button values)

Comment: @swaroopkomma store the previous value on a variable and on changing remove the previous value and append the new

Answer (score 0):

Remove `important` class very first in the change event like following.

```
$('#mc_nos').change(function () {
    $('.important', this).removeClass('important');
    if ($('#mc_nos option:selected')) {
        $("#mc_nos option:selected").addClass("important");
    }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107838/previous-selected-value-also-append-in-textarea-but-i-want-only-one-current-se

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class first:

```
$('#mc_nos').change(function() {
 $('#mc_nos option').removeClass("important");
 if($('#mc_nos option:selected')){
    $("#mc_nos option:selected").addClass("important");
 } 
});
```